# BS4 get XML tag variables

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am playing around with web scraping using bs4 and trying to get the title and color tag from this line of xml `<graph gid="1" color="#000000" balloon_color="#000000" title="Approve">`

The output result would be a dict something along the lines of `{'title':'approve', 'color':'#000000'}`

The page where the xml is [here](http://charts.realclearpolitics.com/charts/1044.xml)

I've already written this function which is by no means efficient, but would like the titles of my dataframe to be the result of the `title` rather than a manually inputted value. So rather than `GID1` it would read `Approve` or `Obama` or whatever the result of title is.

```
def rcp_poll_data(xml):
    soup=bs(xml,"xml")
    dates = soup.find('series')
    datesval = dates.findChildren(string=True)
    del datesval[-7:]
    obama = soup.find('graph', { "gid" : "1" })
    obamaval = obama.findChildren(string=True)
    romney = soup.find('graph', { "gid" : "2" })
    romneyval = romney.findChildren(string=True)
    result = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.to_datetime(datesval), 'GID1':obamaval, 'GID2':romneyval})
    return result
```

I'm using bs4 and struggling to find the right terminology that would get me there. Are these tags i'm trying to isolate, or elements, or attributes?

This isn't a professional thing i'm just nurdling around for fun. So any help to get me slightly closer would be great. (i'm using python 3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to pull the *attributes* once you find the *graph node*:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://charts.realclearpolitics.com/charts/1044.xml").content,"xml")
g = soup.find("graph", gid="1")
data = {"title":g["title"], "color": g["color"]}
```

Which will give you:

```
{'color': '#000000', 'title': 'Approve'}
```

Comment: Damn, I knew it was something simple. Thanks for the help @Padraic

Comment: No worries, obviously for romney we just wash and repeat.